# How to pass Variable from Python to VBA Sub

Tags: python, vba, excel

I am trying to call a VBA sub from my Python code to convert all excel files in a specified folder from the xls to xlsm format.

I can use the following code when I am not using a variable in the VBA and it works well.

**Python Code:**

```
import os
import win32com.client

xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename="C:\Users\Name\Documents\PERSONAL.XLSB", ReadOnly=1)
xl.Application.Run("PERSONAL.XLSB!Module1.xlstoxlsmFinal"
xl.Application.Quit() # Comment this out if your excel script closes
del xl
```

**VBA Code:**

```vb
Public Sub xlstoxlsmFinal()

' goes through all the sub folders of a specified folder and created an xlsm(macro enabled version) of any xls documents


    Dim fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, oFile, queue As Collection

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set queue = New Collection
    Path = "C:\Users\Name\Documents\Monthly Reports\16.06 Reports\Agent Reports"
    queue.Add fso.GetFolder(Path)

    Do While queue.Count > 0
        Set oFolder = queue(1)
        queue.Remove 1 'dequeue
        '...insert any folder processing code here...
        For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.SubFolders
            queue.Add oSubfolder 'enqueue
        Next oSubfolder
        For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
                If Right(oFile, 4) <> "xlsm" And Right(oFile, 3) <> "pdf" Then
                Workbooks.Open Filename:=oFile
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=oFile & "m", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
                ActiveWorkbook.Close
    End If
        Next oFile
    Loop
```

However, I am unable to call the function when I try to pass a variable from python to VBA. Below is what I have tried so far.

**Python code with variable:**

```
import os
import win32com.client

Datev = """16.06 """
xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename="C:\Users\Name\Documents\PERSONAL.XLSB", ReadOnly=1)
xl.Application.Run("PERSONAL.XLSB!Module1.xlstoxlsmFinal(" + Datev + ")")
##    xl.Application.Save() # if you want to save then uncomment this line and change delete the ", ReadOnly=1" part from the open function.
xl.Application.Quit() # Comment this out if your excel script closes
del xl
```

**VBA code with Variable:**

```
Public Sub xlstoxlsmFinal(Datev As String)

' goes through all the sub folders of a specified folder and created an xlsm(macro enabled version) of any xls documents


    Dim fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, oFile, queue As Collection

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set queue = New Collection
    Path = "C:\Users\Name\Documents\Monthly Reports\" & Datev & "Reports\Agent Reports"
    queue.Add fso.GetFolder(Path)

    Do While queue.Count > 0
        Set oFolder = queue(1)
        queue.Remove 1 'dequeue
        '...insert any folder processing code here...
        For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.SubFolders
            queue.Add oSubfolder 'enqueue
        Next oSubfolder
        For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
                If Right(oFile, 4) <> "xlsm" And Right(oFile, 3) <> "pdf" Then
                Workbooks.Open Filename:=oFile
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=oFile & "m", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
                ActiveWorkbook.Close
    End If
        Next oFile
    Loop
```

When I run this in python I get the error message:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Excel', u"Cannot run the macro 'PERSONAL.XLSB!Module1.xlstoxlsmFinal(16.06 )'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.", u'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Would anybody know how to succesfully pass a Python variable to a VBA sub?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm  see the "Returning values..." section at the end of that page.

Comment: Thanks, thats exaclty what I needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per Tim Williams suggestion I read the last section of rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm and formulated the python code

```
    import os
    import win32com.client

    Datev = """16.06 """
    xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename="C:\Users\Name\Documents\PERSONAL.XLSB", ReadOnly=1)
    xl.Application.Run("PERSONAL.XLSB!Module1.xlstoxlsmFinal", Datev)
    xl.Application.Quit() # Comment this out if your excel script closes
    del xl
```

The material difference was changing the line:

```
xl.Application.Run("PERSONAL.XLSB!Module1.xlstoxlsmFinal(" + Datev + ")")
```

To:

```
xl.Application.Run("PERSONAL.XLSB!Module1.xlstoxlsmFinal", Datev)
```

Now the code works perfectly!

Comment: How to pass multiple arguments to vba function ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Macro Security under the developer tag and choose the Enable all macros option

Comment: I don't know if this helps in this particular situation, but have you tried [xlwings](http://xlwings.org/)?

Comment: I saw some references to it when googling around, maybe I will give it a try