# Moving numpy arrays from VBA to Python and back

Tags: python, vba, numpy

I have a VBA script in Microsoft Access.  The VBA script is part of a large project with multiple people, and so it is not possible to leave the VBA environment.

In a section of my script, I need to do complicated linear algebra on a table quickly.  So, I move the VBA tables written as [recordsets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197799.aspx)) into Python to do linear algebra, and back into VBA.  The matrices in python are represented as `numpy` arrays.

Some of the linear algebra is proprietary and so we are compiling the proprietary scripts with [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

The details of the process are as follows:

1. The VBA script creates a csv file representing the table `input.csv`.
2. The VBA script runs the python script through the command line
3. The python script loads the csv file `input.csv` as a `numpy` matrix, does linear algebra on it, and creates an output csv file `output.csv`.
4. VBA waits until python is done, then loads `output.csv`.
5. VBA deletes the no-longer-needed `input.csv` file and `output.csv` file.

This process is inefficient.

**Is there a way to load VBA matrices into Python (and back) without the csv clutter?  Do these methods work with compiled python code through pyinstaller?**

I have found the following examples on stackoverflow that are relevant.  However, they do not address my problem specifically.

[Return result from Python to Vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516875/return-result-from-python-to-vba)

[How to pass Variable from Python to VBA Sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38403790/how-to-pass-variable-from-python-to-vba-sub)

Comment: If the VBA script is there just to create csv from your tables, pass it to Python, get back from Python, and delete the leftovers, then it looks like there is no need to run your code from VBA. Do you know you can [connect MS Access database in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853370/what-do-i-need-to-read-microsoft-access-databases-using-python) using [PYODBC](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyodbc/) / [PYPYODBC](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypyodbc)? If you still need VBA for your goal, please explain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution 1

Either retrieve the COM running instance of Access and get/set the data directly with the python script via the COM API:

**VBA:**

```vbs
Private Cache

Public Function GetData()
  GetData = Cache
  Cache = Empty
End Function

Public Sub SetData(data)
  Cache = data
End Sub

Sub Usage()
  Dim wshell
  Set wshell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

  ' Make the data available via GetData()'
  Cache = Array(4, 6, 8, 9)

  ' Launch the python script compiled with pylauncher '
  Debug.Assert 0 = wshell.Run("C:\dev\myapp.exe", 0, True)

  ' Handle the returned data '
  Debug.Assert Cache(3) = 2
End Sub
```

**Python** (`myapp.exe`):

```py
import win32com.client

if __name__ == "__main__":

  # get the running instance of Access
  app = win32com.client.GetObject(Class="Access.Application")

  # get some data from Access
  data = app.run("GetData")

  # return some data to Access
  app.run("SetData", [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

## Solution 2

Or create a COM server to expose some functions to Access :

**VBA**:

```vbs
Sub Usage()
  Dim Py As Object
  Set Py = CreateObject("Python.MyModule")

  Dim result
  result = Py.MyFunction(Array(5, 6, 7, 8))
End Sub
```

**Python** (`myserver.exe` or `myserver.py`):

```py
import sys, os, win32api, win32com.server.localserver, win32com.server.register

class MyModule(object):

  _reg_clsid_ = "{5B4A4174-EE23-4B70-99F9-E57958CFE3DF}"
  _reg_desc_ = "My Python COM Server"
  _reg_progid_ = "Python.MyModule"
  _public_methods_ = ['MyFunction']

  def MyFunction(self, data) :
    return [(1,2), (3, 4)]


def register(*classes) :
  regsz = lambda key, val: win32api.RegSetValue(-2147483647, key, 1, val)
  isPy = not sys.argv[0].lower().endswith('.exe')
  python_path = isPy and win32com.server.register._find_localserver_exe(1)
  server_path = isPy and win32com.server.register._find_localserver_module()

  for cls in classes :
    if isPy :
      file_path = sys.modules[cls.__module__].__file__
      class_name = '%s.%s' % (os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_path))[0], cls.__name__)
      command = '"%s" "%s" %s' % (python_path, server_path, cls._reg_clsid_)
    else :
      file_path = sys.argv[0]
      class_name = '%s.%s' % (cls.__module__, cls.__name__)
      command = '"%s" %s' % (file_path, cls._reg_clsid_)

    regsz("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\" + cls._reg_progid_ + '\\CLSID', cls._reg_clsid_)
    regsz("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\AppID\\" + cls._reg_clsid_, cls._reg_progid_)
    regsz("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\" + cls._reg_clsid_, cls._reg_desc_)
    regsz("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\" + cls._reg_clsid_ + '\\LocalServer32', command)
    regsz("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\" + cls._reg_clsid_ + '\\ProgID', cls._reg_progid_)
    regsz("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\" + cls._reg_clsid_ + '\\PythonCOM', class_name)
    regsz("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\" + cls._reg_clsid_ + '\\PythonCOMPath', os.path.dirname(file_path))
    regsz("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\" + cls._reg_clsid_ + '\\Debugging', "0")

    print('Registered ' + cls._reg_progid_)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  if len(sys.argv) > 1 :
    win32com.server.localserver.serve(set([v for v in sys.argv if v[0] == '{']))
  else :
    register(MyModule)
```

Note that you'll have to run the script once without any argument to register the class and to make it available to `VBA.CreateObject`.

Both solutions work with `pylauncher` and the array received in python can be converted with `numpy.array(data)`.

Dependency :

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32

Comment: wow, I don't use Python but it is impressive that the OLE Variant is inter-operable with Python arrays.

Comment: Option 2 works great (exact code you gave), except that the result is some kind of [variant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/variant-data-type).  How do I turn the variant into a table, recordset, or some other object I can use?  Or is it already in some usable form?  I'm just not familiar with VBA.

Comment: The marshaler converts the python array to a 1 or 2 dimensions array of variants depending on what you return. It's possible to directly get an array from the recordset with `GetRows` but I don't think it's possible to directly add an array. So you'll probably have to loop over the array to add/update each record.

Comment: Note that you need to return a python array and not a numpy array. You can convert it back with `data.tolist()` or `numpy.asarray`.

Comment: The first solution is frankensteins monster.. the second works perfect though! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try loading your record set into an array, dim'ed as Double

```
Dim arr(1 to 100, 1 to 100) as Double
```

by looping, then pass the pointer to the first element ptr = VarPtr(arr(1, 1)) to Python, where

`arr = numpy.ctypeslib.as_array(ptr, (100 * 100,))`  ?

But VBA will still own the array memory

Comment: Wait, VBA stores arrays as column-major, numpy -- the opposite... Unless your array is 1-dim.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way of doing this with xlwings. See xlwings.org and make sure to follow the instructions to enable macro settings, tick xlwings in VBA references, etc. etc.

The code would then look as simple as the following (a slightly silly block of code that just returns the same dataframe back, but you get the picture):

```
import xlwings as xw

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# the @xw.decorator is to tell xlwings to create an Excel VBA wrapper for this function.
# It has no effect on how the function behaves in python
@xw.func
@xw.arg('pensioner_data', pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=True)
@xw.ret(expand='table', index=False)
def pensioner_CF(pensioner_data, mortality_table = "PA(90)", male_age_adj = 0, male_improv = 0, female_age_adj  = 0, female_improv = 0,
    years_improv = 0, arrears_advance = 0, discount_rate = 0, qxy_tables=0):

    pensioner_data = pensioner_data.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)

    cashflows_df = pd.DataFrame()

    return cashflows_df
```

I'd be interested to hear if this answers the question. It certainly made my VBA / python experience a lot easier.