# Pass a variable from python to vba

Tags: python, excel, vba

I am trying to convert some .csv documents to .xlsx. I do this with the VBA code shown bellow and it works fine, but I want to have path of the file folderes defined as a variable in python and linked to VBA.

```
Sub CSVtoXLSX()


Dim CSVfolder As String, _
    XlsFolder As String, _
    fname As String, _
    wBook As Workbook

 CSVfolder = "pathcsv"
 XlsFolder = "pathxlsx"

 fname = Dir(CSVfolder & "*.csv")

 Do While fname <> ""
    Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(CSVfolder & fname)
    wBook.SaveAs XlsFolder & Replace(fname, ".csv", ""), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    wBook.Close False
    fname = Dir
 Loop

End Sub
```

Also it runs fine when run from python with win32 addon.
The problem arises when I try to define a variable and pass it to VBA.

python code:

```
import win32com.client
CSVfolder = "csvpath"
XlsFolder = "xlsxpath"

xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename = r"macro.xlsm", ReadOnly=1)
xl.Application.Run('CSVtoXLSX', CSVfolder, XlsFolder)
##    xl.Application.Save() # if you want to save then uncomment this line and change delete the ", ReadOnly=1" part from the open function.
xl.Application.Quit() # Comment this out if your excel script closes
del xl
```

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38403790/how-to-pass-variable-from-python-to-vba-sub) thread with almost the same question, but I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/untitled6/exc.py", line 7, in <module>
    xl.Application.Run('CSVtoXLSX', CSVfolder, XLsFolder)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.8\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9\_Application.py", line 370, in Run
    return self._ApplyTypes_(259, 1, (12, 0), ((12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17)), 'Run', None,Macro
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 467, in _ApplyTypes_
    self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(dispid, 0, wFlags, retType, argTypes, *args),
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352562), None)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change your vba function to accept arguments for CSVfolder and Xlsfolder with default values you specify in the body of the function.

```
Sub CSVtoXLSX (Optional CSVfolder As String = "csvpath", Optional Xlsfolder As String = "xlspath")
```

But if all you need to do it convert csv to xlsx, there is a straightforward way to do so in python.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd


CSVfolder = Path("pathcsv")
XlsFolder = Path("pathxlsx")

for f in CSVfolder.glob("*.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    xlsfn = XlsFolder / f.with_suffix('.xlsx').name
    df.to_excel(xlsfn, index=False)
```